# What is the alternative to the Analytics DataAdapterManager in Sitecore XP 8?

Tags: c#, sitecore, analytics, sitecore8

We are in the process of upgrading to Sitecore XP 8 from 7.0. One piece of code we had used to get the "most visited items" from a given starting path used the Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.DataAdapters namespace in order to access the DataAdapterManager class. In Sitecore XP 8 this was moved to the Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.Data.DataAccess.DataAdapters namespace, but is now obsolete.

Here is the code as it stands now:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get topCount most visited items, whose path starts with startPath
/// </summary>
/// <param name="topCount">Max number of items to retrieve</param>
/// <param name="startPath">Url path of the items</param>
/// <returns>Collection of top visited items</returns>
public static IEnumerable<Item> GetMostVisitedItems(int topCount, string startPath)
{
    var sqlQuery = "select top " + topCount.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " "
                            + "{0}ItemId{1} "
                            + "from {0}Pages{1} "
                            + (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(startPath) ? "" : "where {0}Url{1} like '" + startPath + "%' ")
                            + "group by {0}ItemId{1} "
                            + "order by COUNT({0}PageId{1}) desc ";
    var topPageItemIds = DataAdapterManager.Sql.ReadMany<Guid>(sqlQuery, reader => DataAdapterManager.Sql.GetGuid(0, reader));

    return topPageItemIds.Select(itemId => Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(new ID(itemId))).Where(item => item != null);
}
```

Is there a new preferred way to access this same information going forward?

**UPDATE:** Along with the great information from Dmytro Shevchenko below I also found some really good starter information on the LaunchSitecore.net site on the [Accessing Current Visitor Information](http://launchsitecore.net/en/about-launch-sitecore/building-the-site/accessing-current-visitor-information) page. This specific for the session help data of a current visitor, but it helps point out the Sitecore classes and namespaces that are used for analytics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sitecore xDB treats data in a different way compared to the old DMS 2.0. Here's an overview of the new architecture:

https://doc.sitecore.net/en/Products/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/xDB_overview/Architecture_overview.aspx

The data you are requesting is now actually stored in the collection database (MongoDB). There are likely ways to issue a direct MongoDB query that will fetch you the data you need. But that is not what you are supposed to do for a multitude of reasons. For custom queries you should consider designing your own fact/dimension tables in the Reporting Database (RDB), as well as creating your own aggregation pipeline processor.

https://doc.sitecore.net/products/sitecore%20experience%20platform/xdb%20configuration/walkthrough%20creating%20a%20rate%20page%20custom%20aggregation

There are some default fact and dimension tables, though, so you may look into leveraging them as a source for your data.

As to actually issuing queries against the RDB, take a look at the following configuration node in the Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.config:

```
reporting/dataProvider
```

You can instantiate it via Sitecore Factory:

```
var provider = (Reporting.ReportDataProviderBase) Factory.CreateObject("reporting/dataProvider", true);
```

And then issue a query like this:

```
var response = provider.GetData("reporting", "YOUR QUERY HERE", Reporting.CachingPolicy.WithCacheDisabled);
```

If you have a distributed (especially cloud-based) setup, make sure that the server that executes this code either has direct access to the Reporting server or issues queries against a remote reporting service:

https://doc.sitecore.net/en/Products/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/xDB_configuration/Configure_a_reporting_service_server.aspx

Comment: Thank you! This gets me a long way down the road. I will update when I have a chance to dissect this information and put it into practice.